# How do I import an existing android studio project to eclipse so that it is native and becomes a codename application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide, codenameone

How do I import an existing android studio project to eclipse so that it is native and becomes a codename one application?

I've tried importing an existing android project to eclipse however not to the codename one,a software installed on eclipse.

Thank you and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Codename one doesn't currently let you do this because it cannot import android.* packages.

There is this [tutorial on porting an Android application to Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/port-native-android-app-ios-iphone-guide.html)

Comment: How do I use eclipse to build this application when it says you can use eclipse? https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-video-calling/

Comment: Our android migration tool: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/android-migration-tool.html is very partial and works only with NetBeans at this time. Notice that the problem you would have here isn't in importing the Android project which is really trivial and could be easily rewritten. The problem is in supporting the sinch SDK which you will need to do by wrapping it as explained here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html

Comment: FYI made an edit to the answer with an additional link that we published later https://www.codenameone.com/blog/port-native-android-app-ios-iphone-guide.html